# How to give all Sales Reps read-only on all New Opportunities, but restrict them from changing Opp Owner

Tags: opportunity, sharing, sharing-rule, territory-management, territory

Sales Rep Users need the ability to see (Read only) all New Opportunities no matter what territory they are in, no matter who is the Owner.

We set this up successfully by creating a Sharing rule where Opportunity Type = New.

The issue is that now Sales Rep Users can now change the Opportunity Owner. How can we disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Opportunity Owner field on the page layout Read Only. Or you could remove their profile permission to transfer records. Or use a validation rule and have ISCHANGED(ownerId) as part of the criteria.

Comment: Thanks David, the first two suggestions would prevent User of Same Territory from changing the Owner field. Is there a way with Validation Rule to include check for User's Territory same as Opportunity's Territory.